# Sending two values from formbuilder in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I have the following formbuilder:

```
this.rForm = this.fb.group(
  {
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required),
    retypepassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required)
  }
```

I want to send it using http, there is my code:

```
this.userService.registerUser(this.rForm.value)
```

This code send whole rForm, I need to send only email and password.
How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit) `omit` function

```
let reqBody = _.omit(this.rForm.value, 'retypepassword')
this.userService.registerUser(reqBody)
```

Or by using plain JS

```
let {email,password} = this.rForm.value;
this.userService.registerUser({email, password})
```

Comment: where should i post this code ? My codes are in different methods.

Comment: put above code where you have this `this.userService.registerUser(this.rForm.value)` code or if you are not clear then share methods you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// If you need whole form value
const wholeFormValue = this.rForm.getRawValue();

const email = this.rForm.get('email').value;
const password = this.rForm.get('password').value;

// Assign to a local variable like this: 
const registerUserRequestBody = { email, password };
 
// Or like this: 
const reqBody = Object.assign({}, {email, password});

this.userService.registerUser(registerUserRequestBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get form control value you can do
`this.rForm.value.email` and `this.rForm.value.password` respectively. So in your case I would do smth like this

```
const sendParams = {
    email: this.rForm.value.email,
    password: this.rForm.value.password
 }

this.userService.registerUser(sendParams)
```